# JSF 2.0 Error at startup

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2

I have a problem configuring my JSF page.
I used to use JSF in a software project, but that was some time ago. Now I need it for a private project and have a huge problem starting my JSF page. 
Because it was some time ago i used it last, I decided to follow a tutorial to start. It was [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html). I tried to run it on a Tomcat 6.0 on my localhost, but I got an error showing up on the page.

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.net.URLStreamHandler.equals(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URL.equals(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:95)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:256)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:366)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:308)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:367)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
```

And I have no idea, why. The code is exatly as in the tutorial. And here is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

I hope you can help me.
Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys,
I just tried everything, deleting piece by piece of code and see what happens.
And i figured out that

```
<ui:composition template="">
```

Is making problems. Just deleted it and everything works fine.

Comment: You were recursively including the very same template in an infinite loop.